# UWP slider; hide the value displayed on top

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, uwp, slider

I'm using a Slider control in my UWP app.  I need to get rid of the value that is displayed on the top when I'm dragging the thumb of the slider.

Tried to edit the template but cannot find that anywhere.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set `IsThumbToolTipEnabled` to `False` in XAML:

```
<Slider IsThumbToolTipEnabled="False"/>
```

Comment: Thanks!  I spent way too much time on this simple one! :)

Comment: @danbord My pleasure.